# How to access a shared location in solaris from windows machine using samba with java?

Tags: java, sockets, window, solaris, samba

I need to access the shared location which is located in solaris  machine from a windows machine using a java program. i wrote a code but when it run  it throwing a run time exception. please see the code below and error

```
public class SambaDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String user = "username";
        String pass = "password";

        String sharedFolder = "shared";
        String path = "smb://1**.**.**.**/";
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", user, pass);
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
        SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
        smbfos.write("testing....and writing to a file".getBytes());
        System.out.println("completed ...nice !");
    }
}
```

please see the error i got

```
Exception in thread "main" jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: hostname/***.**.**.**
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:352)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:214)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:378)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:537)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:487)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:198)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.ssn139(SmbTransport.java:185)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:247)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doConnect(SmbTransport.java:312)
    at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:232)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)

    at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:248)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)

    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.connect(SmbTransport.java:299)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:156)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:906)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:949)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:875)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:965)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:999)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:67)
    at com.java.samba.test.SambaDemo.main(SambaDemo.java:18)
```

in order to run u need to give the hostname,ip address , username and password. I'm expecting some expert help for this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" means that host is not listening on that port.  You need to ensure the samba service is running on that host.

I would check you can mount the file system as a drive letter first.

Comment: Its mean do i need to install samba in solaris?

Comment: @stacktome If you want to use samba on solaris, it needs to be installed and configured.